# Jquery object array references in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I have html like this...

```
<div id="parentDiv">
  <div class="childLine">
    hello1
  </div>
  <div class="childLine">
    hello2
  </div>
  <div class="childLine">
    hello3
  </div>
</div>
```

And I want to use javascript to remove the last appearing instance of childLine (i.e. in this example the div containing hello3).

So I'm doing this...

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#parentDiv .childLine")[$("#parentDiv .childLine").length-1].style = "display:none";
 });
```

Here's the live example: https://codepen.io/d3wannabe/pen/BRRQBv

If you open that in Chrome or Firefox you'll only see the first 2 lines (correctly), whereas if you open in Safari the third div will not be removed.  Likewise on the iPhone (even using the Chrome app) the third div remains.

Any ideas why I'm seeing inconsistent results across browsers?

Comment: Simple `$("#parentDiv .childLine:last").hide();` would work

Comment: Thanks Satpal.  Still not sure I understand why my original approach didn't work, but you have indeed immediately (and simply) solved the problem!

Comment: You should have used `style.display = "none"`